# Remove files in a directory based on partial name

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

I wanted to know what is the best way to remove any files no matter what their extension is based on a partial name.

Example:

```
13-05-12_foo_something.jpg
13-06-01_something.png
13-05-05_foo_site.html
```

rm everything in a directory and within the sub folders with `_foo_` in the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way:

```
cd /path/to/directory
rm *_foo_*
```

or

```
rm /path/to/directory/*_foo_*
```

The asterisk (`*`) matches all characters.

To get explanations about what is being done, use `rm` with `-v` option. To be prompted before every removal, use `rm` with `-i` option:

```
rm -vi *_foo_*
```

See `man rm` for more info.

Comment: Thanks I was unaware you could do that with `*` before and after.

Comment: @Matt_2.0 You can use it as many times as you want: `rm *foo_1*foo_2*...*foo_n*`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in all subdirectories too, the easiest way is to enable the globstar shell option:

```
shopt -s globstar
rm **/*foo_*
```

There should be a commented (i.e. starting with a `#`) line in the default `~/.bashrc` (line 29 in mine):

```
# shopt -s globstar extglob
```

Just uncomment that line and you'll have access to some [improved bash features](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).